Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Object value
I'm trying to put a condition in the field: Print When Expression
$F{CARTEIRA_FORMATADA}.floatValue() > $F{DESCRICOES}.floatValue() 

but it gives me an error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Object
value = ((java.lang.Integer)field_CARTEIRA_FORMATADA.getValue()).floatValue() > ((java.lang.Integer)field_DESCRICOES.getValue()).floatValue(); 

input values are 0 and 1, tried as Float, String (using ==), but always the same error
I need to place a condition using 1 or more fields, in 'Print When Expression', and it always gives me an error converting from boolean to Object

What is the type of these two fields (CARTEIRA_FORMATADA, DESCRICOES)? It is better to post small jrxml that illustrates a problem

java.lang.Integer    I'm trying now simpler: $E{DESCRICOES}.float Value()=0

I think your expression return a boolean but probably the system is looking for a Boolean(wrapper class) object.
you can cast it to a wrapper Boolean like this.
new Boolean($F{CARTEIRA_FORMATADA}.floatValue() > $F{DESCRICOES}.floatValue() );

try this.

Error evaluating expression for source text: new Boolean($F{DESCRICOES}.floatValue()==0)

I simplified it to new Boolean($F{DESCRIPTIONS}.floatValue()==0)

can you provide me more details..!
